# How to use the CartoDb baselayers from ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: carto, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've been trying to make use of the CartoDB baseLayers (https://carto.com/location-data-services/basemaps/) in the ArcGis Javascript API v 4.0.

But I have not been able to get it working.

I believe it is correct to make use of the WebTileLayer, and with single domain access I attempted to add it like this:

```
var layer = new WebTileLayer("http://1.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{level}/{col}/{row}.png", {
    "id": "cartoDb",
    "copyright": '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>'
    });
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was investigating a bit more myself.

First, the WebTiledLayer has been renamed to WebTileLayer (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/whats-new/index.html#New_Widgets_52)

Then secondly, using version 4.0, it seems to be mandatory to use the MapView object.

Initializing the map object this way works:

```
 map = new Map({});

   view = new MapView({
      center: [-111.87, 40.57], // long, lat
      container: "map",
      map: map,
      zoom: 6
    });
```

Doing it like what worked for 3.17 doesn't:

```
map = new Map("map", {
      center: [-89.985, 29.822],
      zoom: 8
    });*/
```

Full working example in fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/eivind_ronnevik/tny749fc/

Thanks for the effort anyway @ramiroaznar

Comment: Well done! Good to know, you can mark your question as answered then.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you have shared, it could be the rest of the code. Maybe you are missing `map.addLayer(layer);` just after those lines. [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/ramiroaznar/869b9f2de099a49af10953f214d441e7) I have created a working example replicating [the one from `WebTiledLayer` class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_webtiled_one.html).

[image]

Comment: Sorry, pushed the enter button too early.

I was initially working with version 4.0, but I got your example to work using API version 3.17 instead, see this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eivind_ronnevik/p5hwzj07/

However, when trying the same with version 4.0, it doesn't work. Modified version of html for version 4.0:
https://jsfiddle.net/eivind_ronnevik/osauzsae/

Comment: I have not used v4 before, but a little research tell me that the classes have changed, from `WebTileLayer` to `TileLayer`. I will try, but maybe someone can give you a faster answer.